# How can I solve the differential equation $r'=r(1-r)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I seperated the variables and decomposed the fraction to get $r(1-r)=ce^t$, but I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: I think you got $r/(1-r) = ce^t$, not $r(1-r) = ce^t$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\dfrac {dr}{r(1-r)}=dt$$
$$ \left({\dfrac 1 r- \dfrac 1{(r-1)}}\right)dr=dt$$
Integrate:
$$\ln r -\ln (r-1)=t+c$$
$$\dfrac r {r-1}=ke^t$$
$$ r(1- ke^t)=-ke^t$$
$$ r(t)=\dfrac {ke^t}{ke^t-1}$$
Finally:
$$ r(t)=\dfrac {e^t}{e^t+C}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{r'}{r\left(1-r\right)}=1$$
I suppose you integrated this incorrectly.
$$\int \left(\frac{1}{r}+\frac{1}{1-r}\right) \; dr = \int  dt$$

$$\ln{\left(\frac{r}{1-r}\right)}=t+C_1$$
$$\left(\frac{r}{1-r}\right)=C_2 e^t$$
Isolating r yields:
$$r(t)=\frac{C_2 e^t}{1+C_2 e^t}$$